# What is the strong association rule if there is only candidate 1-Itemsets possible after using Apriori algorithm?

Tags: data-mining, apriori

Well for a question if I solve it I get only candidate 1-Itemsets after removing itemsets of low support. Now for the strong association rule for example can I take it as Pencil->Pencil and write it as the answer?

Comment: That is not an association rule, by definition. Try more carefully following the definitions and procedure.

Comment: If that is not an association rule then should we directly take single element i.e. say Pencil and say it directly has 100% confidence?

Comment: Look at the definition of how a rule relates to a frequent itemset.